# How do I get uploading status of Video on Youtube Api?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, status, uploading

I am developing an application is uploading video to youtube with Youtube Api 2.0 on C#

Here is my code

```
    Video newVideo = new Video();

    newVideo.Title = "kankaaaa";
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Keywords = "education, funny deneme";
    newVideo.Description = "bilgi mi istiyorsun";
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
    YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\cat.flv",
          "video/quicktime");      
   // newVideo.Private = true;

 Video createdVideo = Request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Video class is under **Google.YouTube namespace.**

I can upload video without any problem.  When Requested completed it returns an object which type is Video.

But I want to see detail of processing. I mean percent of uploading. I searched and I found two functions  are getUploadState() and getProgress(). But I cant find it on youtube api.

there is just [Status class](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astate) member of the Video Class.  It shows result of video. But I want to learn uploading process detail. Such as 40% completed..

What should I use ?  I thought that I could Backgroundworker but I am not sure if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.. it was a bit difficult but I finally did :)

```
public bool InsertVideo()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Entering InsertVideo: starting a new upload");
        Video newVideo = new Video();

        newVideo.Title = "MY video";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "education, funny deneme";
        newVideo.Description = "bilgi mi istiyorsun";
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
          YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\cat.flv",
          "video/quicktime");
        // newVideo.Private = true;

        GDataCredentials credentials = new GDataCredentials(UserName, PassWord);

        Authenticator youTubeAuthenticator =new ClientLoginAuthenticator("YoutubeUploader",
                    ServiceNames.YouTube, credentials);
        youTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = DevKey;


        AtomLink link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/" + UserName + "/uploads");
        link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);

        ResumableUploader ru = new ResumableUploader();
        ru.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(this.OnDone);
        ru.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(this.OnProgress);
        var tmpvalue = "bla bla bla";
        ru.InsertAsync(youTubeAuthenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, tmpvalue);



        return true;
    }

    private void OnProgress(object sender, AsyncOperationProgressEventArgs e)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("It has been completed : " + e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void OnDone(object sender, AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("It has Done");
    }
```

And you can access information of uploaded video  in OnDone event with AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e parameter and property is ResponseStream